# Show that function is primitive recursive.

Tags: computability

Having trouble with showing that function is primitive recursive. Have the following problem.

> Let $ f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be decreasing function. Show 
>   that $f$ is primitive recursive.

I see that $f$ will eventually decrease to a certain constant and that I could say that it is a constant function with over certain numbers which would make it primitive recursive. I don't think this is enough, however, and that I need something more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why isn't that enough?  An algorithm to calculate it could be of the form

```
if n = 1 then return ...
else if n = 2 then return ...
else ...
else return ...
```

Comment: Because the function isn't a constant function and it turns into one eventually. I think I am just misunderstanding some part of this but I don't think this would be a proper proof.

Comment: There are various characterizations of primitive recursive functions.  One is: a function that can be computed using an algorithm that contains a limited set of instructions: constants, the successor function, equals, if-then-else, and bounded loops.

Comment: So because I know that the function will turn into a constant at a certain point $n$ that is less than infinity I can say that the function will limited number of intructions which is pretty much the definition of primitive recursion. I think I got it now.